# my nodes don't send (receive) messages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello everyone
I created a class **stage_listener**; then, in an externally defined main() function, an object of class **stage_listener** is created and its function **listen** is invoked.
The purpose of this function is forcing the object of class **stage_listener** to become a listener of certain kinds of messages. Here is the code of function:

```
void stage_listener::listen(int c, char **v){
    while_flag = 1;
    ROS_INFO("Listening activity begun");
    ros::init(c,v, "listener");
    ros::NodeHandle n_odom, n_scan, n_end;
/*  std_msgs::String s;
    end_loop(s);*/

    //ros::Subscriber sub_odom = n_odom.subscribe("/odom", 1000, &stage_listener::end_loop,this);
    ros::Subscriber sub_odom = n_odom.subscribe("/odom", 1000, &stage_listener::addOdomNode,this);
    ros::Subscriber sub_scan = n_scan.subscribe("/base_scan", 1000, &stage_listener::addScanNode,this);
    ros::Subscriber sub_end = n_end.subscribe("/end", 1000, &stage_listener::end_loop,this);
    
    while(while_flag){
        //ros::Subscriber sub_odom = n_odom.subscribe("/odom", 1000, &stage_listener::end_loop,this);
        ros::spinOnce();
    }
    ROS_INFO("Exit from while");
}
```

The function receives, as parameters, the **argc** and **argv** of the main() where object has been created, since such parameters are requested by **ros::init**.
These are the functions used for listening:

```
void stage_listener::end_loop(const std_msgs::String mes){
    ROS_INFO("Setting flag");
    ROS_INFO("%s",mes.data.c_str());
    while_flag = 0;
}

void stage_listener::addOdomNode (const nav_msgs::Odometry mes){
    geometry_msgs::Pose robot_pose = mes.pose.pose;
    geometry_msgs::Point robot_point = robot_pose.position;

    odom_node *on = new odom_node();
    (*on).xCoord = robot_point.x;
    (*on).yCoord = robot_point.y;
    (*on).frame_id = mes.header.frame_id;
    
    double orientation = tf::getYaw(robot_pose.orientation);
    (*on).angle = (float)orientation;
    
    odom_list.push_back(*on);
}

void stage_listener::addScanNode (const sensor_msgs::LaserScan mes){
    scan_node *sn = new scan_node();
    (*sn).scan = mes.ranges;
    (*sn).frame_id = mes.header.frame_id;
    (*sn).cartesian = polar2cart(mes.ranges, mes.angle_min, mes.angle_increment, mes.range_min, mes.range_max);
    
    scan_list.push_back(*sn);
}
```

After invocation of function **listen**, the object created begins to wait for messages. An external node, in another package, prepares and sends an **std_msgs::String** message:

```
#include "std_msgs/String.h"
#include "ros/ros.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv,"end_bag");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    
    ros::Publisher chatter_pub = n.advertise("/end",1000);
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);
    
    std_msgs::String msg;
    msg.data = "end of loop";
    
    chatter_pub.publish(msg);
    
    ROS_INFO("Message sent: %s",msg.data.c_str());
    
    ros::spinOnce();
    //sleep(3);
    loop_rate.sleep();
    
    exit(0);
}
```

The problem is that the message created is never received by the waiting object, since it remains iterating on **spinOnce()** instruction, never exiting the loop, a result that should be granted by reception of message.

Can you individuate any error in my code causing receiver node not to get any message?
thanks for support.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50712/my-nodes-don%27t-send-(receive)-messages/) by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2012-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your sender does NOT remain iterating in the `spinOnce()` instruction. As the name says: It only spins once. Thus, your sender will exit before anyone has connected. Use `ros::spin()` or put the spinOnce in a while loop to keep the program running.

Alternatively, you can wait until `chatter_pub.getNumSubscribers() > 0` to make sure someone has connected before the program quits.

In general, when testing publish/subscribe: Use `rostopic echo` and `rostopic pub` in place of a subscriber/publisher to isolate where the error comes from.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ubisum](https://answers.ros.org/users/3549/ubisum/) on 2012-12-18**:
thanks for answer. let's suppose that message sent by node has to be stored into a bag file. the process (started from a shell) waiting for messages to store in bag file, is considered a subscriber? will it increment the number of subscribers of topic?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-12-18**:
Yes and yes.